# Maven is making unwanted changes to the Eclipse .classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, pom.xml

I recently added some new items to my pom.xml.  For some reason, after adding these new items, and I run a Maven project update, it modifies the Eclipses .classpath.

Here are the pom.xml items that were added:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the .classpath after Maven does a project update, it adds:   including="**/*.java"

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry including="**/*.java" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>

...

</classpath>
```

Because of this, when I run the java, none of my resources are being found because they're not .java.  I'm not sure why those new items that were added to Maven, are making it suddenly modify the Eclipse .classpath.  I tried manually removing the including="**/*.java", but once Maven does another project update, it puts it back.

Does anyone have an idea why this is occurring?  I appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: First the change in the `.classpath` is not done by Maven it's done via the Maven integration in Eclipse (m2e?) ...The question is: Why is this a problem? What do you mean by ..`Because of this, when I run the java, none of my resources are being found because they're not .java`... Resources are located in `src/main/resources` or for test resources in `src/test/resources`... ?

Comment: True, I can move my properties files into a resource package.  I'm still curious why the Maven integration in Eclipse added to the classpath to only look at java sources.

Comment: You can move them? I strongly recommend you should do. The problem is not related only to Maven or Eclipse etc. it violates the idea of Maven... The integration in your IDE tries to map the information into the internal information of Eclipse in this case to find all the files and the correct directories (the default as far as I know). Furthermore I strongly recommend to keep your fingers off those files cause they will be regenerated every time...so changing them manually does not make sense. The truth is the pom.xml file....

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven in Eclipse, then the m2e plugin controls the `.classpath` file.

You need to manage your resources through the POM, not through `.classpath`.

Comment: By resources, I meant property files.  Not java resources. application.properties, etc.  Because the .classpath was changed to only look at .java objects, anything else, like property files are not visible as a resource during runtime.

Comment: Put them into `src/main/resources` as khmarbaise said. Or configure another resource directory in the POM.